# HEROKU and DOCKER containing .NET Core 3.1 Console App, Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 120 seconds of launch

Tags: c#, .net, docker, heroku, procfile

I deployed a docker container containing a .NET core 3.1 console app on Heroku and I get following error when starting my app:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 120 seconds of launch.
```

I changed the timeout, I also found out about that it has something to do with a Procfile in the root of the project but I haven't used that yet.

What's causing this error and why does this error occur?

Comment: See following : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes?force_isolation=true

Comment: Hi and thanks for the resource! Is there also a potential solution to this problem suited for my setup?